# How re-order rows when row is hidden

Tags: javascript

I want to be re-order the based on which field has been hidden, I set the hidden field zone  zone_deleted to 1 when it it has been hidden to mark it as deleted.

```
function insertZone() {

    var table = document.getElementById('zoneItems');

    var e = document.getElementById('zone');
    var number = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var rowcount = document.getElementById('zoneItems').rows.length;

    if(rowcount == 0){
        var x = table.insertRow(-1);

        var head1 = x.insertCell(0);
        head1.innerHTML = "Zone";

        var head2 = x.insertCell(1);
        head2.innerHTML = "Motor Reference Point";

        var head3 = x.insertCell(2);
        head3.innerHTML = " ";

    }

        for (var i=0; i < number; i++)
        {
            var x = table.insertRow(-1);
            var a = x.insertCell(0);
            //a.innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' name='zone_id' value='' /> ";

            num = i+1;

            var b = x.insertCell(1);
            b.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='zone_description[]' size='18' value=''/><input id='zone"+num+"' type='hidden' name='zone_deleted[]' value='0' />";

            var c = x.insertCell(2);
            c.innerHTML = "<button type='button' class='button lastChild' onclick='removeZone(this)' ><img src='themes/default/images/id-ff-clear.png'></button>";
        }

        //set the row ordering
        count();

}

function removeZone(rows) {

    var _row = rows.parentElement.parentElement;

    _row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = '1';

    document.getElementById('zoneItems').rows[_row.rowIndex].style.display = 'none';

    count();


}

function count(){ //sets the row ordering

    var table = document.getElementById("zoneItems");
    var tbody = table.tBodies[0];

    for (var i = 0, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) { //loop through rows

        if(i != 0){//if not the first row

           // var deleted = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;


            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {//loop through cols


                if(j == 0){//insert into only the first td
                    col.innerHTML = "<span>" +i+ "</span><input type='hidden' name='zone_id' value='' />";
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't understand the question. I don't see any reordering in your code.

Comment: count() loops through the rows and sets the innerHTML of the first cell in each row to i e.g the row number. removeZone(rows) sets the row to hidden and calls count() again. I want count to loop through the rows but miss out the hidden rows as they are marked for deletion. Make sense?

Comment: Here is a working version of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/6CJGp/8/

Comment: I think you mean "renumber", not "reorder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different variable for the row number that's displayed than the one used to index the rows in the DOM.

```
function count() {
    var table = document.getElementById("zoneItems");
    var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
    var rownum = 1;

    for (var i = 1, row; row = tbody.rows[i]; i++) { //loop through rows
        var deleted = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
        if (deleted != "1") {
            row.cells[0].innerHTML = "<span>" +rownum+ "</span><input type='hidden' name='zone_id' value='' />";
            rownum++;
        }
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6CJGp/9/)

Comment: thanks thats great, my brain was reaching melt down with this.